# How do I break the one dimensional array when condition met?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to enter an array of numbers (only integers for now) and what I wan't to do is if the user enters all the needed numbers, give him the ability to break the operation of entering numbers and skip to printing the entered numbers. My code is below. So the thing is, I've set 100 array elements, but if only have 5 to enter I don't wan't to enter the other 95. 
Commented code is what I've tried and it didn't work. ( I work in CodeBlocks and am a total beginner, so I'm still learning this...)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
//Declaring variables

int one_d_array[100],counter=0;

printf("Enter a list of numbers(max. 100)\nTo end, enter two zeros (00)\n");
for (counter=0;counter<5;counter++){
    scanf("%d",&one_d_array[counter]);

    /*if (one_d_array[counter]==00){
        break;
    }*/

}
printf("Entered list is:\n");
for (counter=0;counter<5;counter++){
    printf("%d\n",one_d_array[counter]);
}
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could first ask how many the user wants to enter, and then use that as your loop condition.

Comment: `1d_array` does that compile? and you can never have `00` as an integer! better scan to a string and perform atoi if not `"00"`, that would work.

Comment: Variable names may not start with digits

Comment: Two zeros are the same as one zero. Use an invalid value (e.g. `-1` if you only allow non-negative numbers) as the stop value, or check the return value from `scanf` and use `q` to quit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you for correcting me, I edited my variable names (forgot about all the basics since I haven't studied C in a year)

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for informing me, however I wan't to make a special input if a user want's stop entering numbers

Comment: @immibis I've enter wrong variables, but after correcting, I get wrong outputs.

[![2016-10-06_231928.png](https://s21.postimg.org/mimnmhb1j/2016_10_06_231928.png)](https://postimg.org/image/vqew36i3n/)

Comment: @Istvan That's because the code you actually wrote is different from the code in the question. Specifically the line with `scanf`. Can you spot the difference?

Comment: @immibis Yes, I didn't edit it, since I'm trying multiple solutions too fast, so I posted this screenshot at the time of trying out. The `scanf` is with %s string call, because I was trying out fellow users suggestion.

Comment: Try my answer and see if that works. I had misunderstood a few things, but I think I've worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` can be used to input a line. If the line is `00` exit the loop. Otherwise `sscanf` tries to scan a number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void)
{
    int one_d_array[100],each=0,counter=0;
    char input[99] = "";

    printf("Enter a list of numbers(max. 100)\nTo end, enter two zeros (00)\n");
    while ( 1){
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof ( input), stdin)) {//get a line
            if ( strcmp ( input, "00\n") == 0) {//exit on 00
                break;
            }
            if ( ( sscanf(input, "%d",&one_d_array[counter])) != 1) {// != 1 means sscanf failed
                printf("could not scan a number try again\n");
                continue;
            }
            counter++;
            printf("numbers input: %d\n\n", counter);
            if ( counter >= 100) {
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem reading input\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }
    }
    printf("Entered list is:\n");
    for (each=0;each<counter;each++){
        printf("%d\n",one_d_array[each]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable names cannot start with a number, so I've edited it accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
//Declaring variables

int oneD_array[100],counter=0, num=0;
char c[3];

do{
    printf("Enter your %d number, q to quit", counter+1);
    scanf("%s",&c);
    if(c == "q" || c == "Q"){
        break;
    }
    else{
        num = atoi(c);
        oneD_array[num];
        counter++;
    }


}while(c != "q");
printf("Entered list is:\n");
for (int i = 0;i<counter;i++){
    printf("%d\n",oneD_array[i]);
}
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works but not in the way I need it to, it's a nice workaround, the trouble is I don't want user to enter the number in advance, a scenario I have in my head is when you're entering school grades or perhaps daily expenses and you don't know how much of those entries is going to be.

Comment: It is the needed solution, except the condition variable at the end, screenshot at the link. https://postimg.org/image/rt2oy007n/

Comment: Ah yes. My bad, i forgot to edit that out. Will update.

Comment: There. I also forgot to change the `while` to use `c` instead of `counter`. Also fixed that. Changed the loop to print out only those numbers that were entered `counter` times.

Comment: Sorry man, didn't work actually, you need to initalize the `i variable` before using it in `for loop` and also you can't seem to use `int i` in the loop. I'll get my head around it the next days, but this has been helpfull alot.

Comment: Its been awhile since I've used `c`. Try putting `int i;`at the top of the program where the other variables are, and use `i=0` in the loop.